# Selector Layer - fflib_SObjectSelector error on Cross-Object and Sub-Select Queries

Tags: fflib

I'm working on a skipe for this fflib and I'm facing this error when I try to execute a **Cross-Object or Sub-Select query**:.

> |WARN|fflib_QueryFactory.subselectQuery(Schema.SObjectType) is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use fflib_QueryFactory.subselectQuery(String) or fflib_QueryFactory.subselectQuery(ChildRelationship) instead.

I'm basically following the Trailhead: [Apex Enterprise Patterns: Domain & Selector Layers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl).

On the last section of this module, [Apply Selector Layer Principles in Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_apply_selector_l_principles) there is a part explaining how to reuse field list: **Advanced: Reusing Field Lists for Cross-Object and Sub-Select Queries**

```
public List<Opportunity> selectByIdWithProducts(Set<ID> idSet) {

    // Query Factory for this Selector (Opportunity)
    fflib_QueryFactory opportunitiesQueryFactory = newQueryFactory();

    // Add a query sub-select via the Query Factory for the Opportunity Products
    fflib_QueryFactory lineItemsQueryFactory =
        new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().
            addQueryFactorySubselect(opportunitiesQueryFactory);

    // Add cross object query fields for Pricebook Entry, Products and Pricebook
    new PricebookEntriesSelector().
        configureQueryFactoryFields(lineItemsQueryFactory, 'PricebookEntry');
    new ProductsSelector().
        configureQueryFactoryFields(lineItemsQueryFactory, 'PricebookEntry.Product2');
    new PricebooksSelector().
        configureQueryFactoryFields(lineItemsQueryFactory, 'PricebookEntry.Pricebook2');

    // Set the condition and build the query
    return (List<Opportunity>) Database.query(
        opportunitiesQueryFactory.setCondition('id in :idSet').toSOQL());
}
```

When executing this method I get the error mentioned on the top of this question. I have tried several things but I still get the same error. All the test code is updated from classes on this [repository](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common-samplecode). Anyone has ever faced similar issue with this library?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do ... (some variable renaming to make it more compact)

```
public List<Opportunity> selectByIdWithProducts(Set<ID> ids) {

    if (ids.isEmpty()) {return new List<Opportunity>();}  // avoid burning soql
    // Query Factory for this Selector (Opportunity)
    fflib_QueryFactory oQF = newQueryFactory()
                               .setCondition('Id IN : ids');

    // Add a query sub-select via the Query Factory for the Opportunity Products
    fflib_QueryFactory oliQF = oQF.subSelectQuery('OpportunityLineItems')
                                .selectFields(new OpportunityLineItemsSelector()
                                                  .getSObjectFieldList());


    // Add cross object query fields for Pricebook Entry, Products and Pricebook
    new PricebookEntriesSelector().
        configureQueryFactoryFields(oliQF, 'PricebookEntry');
    new ProductsSelector().
        configureQueryFactoryFields(oliQF, 'PricebookEntry.Product2');
    new PricebooksSelector().
        configureQueryFactoryFields(oliQF, 'PricebookEntry.Pricebook2');

    // Set the condition and build the query
    return  Database.query(oQF.toSOQL());
}
```

The key is here:

```
// Add a query sub-select via the Query Factory for the Opportunity Products
    fflib_QueryFactory oliQF = oQF.subSelectQuery('OpportunityLineItems')
                                .selectFields(new OpportunityLineItemsSelector()
                                                  .getSObjectFieldList());
```

Use of the relationship name in the argument avoids the deprecation error you see